# No sound output from Guitarix

Tags: arch-linux, audio, jack

I've installed Guitarix on Arch Linux. When I start up the program, I also start QJackCtl.

When strumming my guitar, I can see the EQ levels on Guitarix rising and falling as I play. But I hear nothing from my headphones.

Here's the output of QJackCtl messages.

```
19:00:24.576 Statistics reset.
19:00:24.577 ALSA connection change.
19:00:24.586 JACK is starting...
19:00:24.587 /usr/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:Adapter
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
jackd 0.125.0
Copyright 2001-2009 Paul Davis, Stephane Letz, Jack O'Quinn, Torben Hohn and others.
jackd comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
19:00:24.595 ALSA connection graph change.
JACK compiled with System V SHM support.
cannot lock down memory for jackd (Cannot allocate memory)
loading driver ..
creating alsa driver ... hw:Adapter|hw:Adapter|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
JACK: unable to mlock() port buffers: Cannot allocate memory
19:00:24.670 JACK was started with PID=4043.
19:00:26.796 JACK connection change.
19:00:26.796 Server configuration saved to "/home/chris/.jackdrc".
19:00:26.796 Statistics reset.
19:00:26.798 Client activated.
19:00:26.798 Patchbay deactivated.
19:00:26.802 Buffer size change (1024).
cannot lock down memory for RT thread (Cannot allocate memory)
```

And here's how the hookups look in QJackCtl's graph.
[image]

Comment: `Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback.` means exactly that: Jack can't use hardware for playback, so you can't hear anything. That usually happens because *something else* (like Pulseaudio, which is the default on most distros) is using it. So (1) find out what is using the hardware, (2a) don't run that thing, (2b) run it in such a way that it is compatible with jack. Details depend on what actually happens on your system, if you need e.g. Pulseaudio for something else, etc.

Comment: How do I accomoplish step 1? I am using the Rocksmith USB cable.

Comment: To check for Pulseaudio, do e.g. `ps axu | grep pulse` in a terminal, or do `pavucontrol` - if you see the controls, it is running. In that case, edit your question and provide information if you need Pulseaudio for other applications, if you only want to play your guitar occasionally, or if you are using that computer only to play guitar, etc. - that will determine the best solution, and we cannot guess the circumstances.

Comment: @Username I am not on Arch (AVLinux) but having the same problem. Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have two separate issues in your error log:

##### Permission/Memory Allocation error

When jackd starts your log shows:

```bsh
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such 
file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
```

which likely stems from incomplete privilege/permission settings required for jackd to start properly.

1. You need to start by installing the [`realtime-privileges`](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=realtime-privileges) package, per [JACK Audio Connection Kit wiki.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit#Installation)
2. Make sure your user belongs to the `realtime` group
3. Reboot

---

If the above does not solve the all the issues by itself, and you still see the following memory allocation issues:

```bsh
cannot lock down memory for jackd (Cannot allocate memory)
....
JACK: unable to mlock() port buffers: Cannot allocate memory
```

you can then also make sure the user starting jackd belongs to the `audio` group, and check `/etc/security/limits.conf` for allocation limits, and if needed set the following for `audio`:

```bsh
audio - memlock unlimited
# unlimited allocatable memory for group audio

audio - nice -10
# priority with respect to idletime scheduling of processes (see idprio in BSD)
# nice -20 is the highest priority

audio - rtprio 99   
# priority with respect to realtime scheduling of non-priveleged processes.
# rtprio 99 - highest hard limit
```

The error is related to either privilege settings, or memory allocation settings, or both.

---

#### ALSA OUTPUT

You also have an issue with alsa where it falls back down to capture-only mode. There have been some issues with previous `alsa-lib` and `alsa-plugins` but they apparently have been mostly fixed in the most recent release. In order to allow `alsa` to play streams while `jack` is running you need to make sure you have the corresponding `jack` plugin and make some changes to `asound.conf`:

1. First you need to make sure you have [alsa-plugins](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=alsa-plugins) installed, as the required `jack` plugin is found in that package.
2. The enable it by edition your `/etc/asound.conf` and add the following:

```bsh
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "jack"
    hint.description "Jack Audio"
}
```

3. Restart `jack` as user